# Do Player characters know they are under the effect of a Death Tyrant's Negative Energy Cone?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

My players will be going up against a Death Tyrant very soon. The Negative Energy Cone states it is an invisible cone. Does this mean player characters won't know they are affected by it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Creatures won't notice they are affected

At least, not until specific things occur as a result of being in the cone.

> **Targets (of spells) PHB 204**
>
> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature might not know it
> was targeted by a spell at all. An effect like crackling lightning is
> obvious, but a more subtle effect, such as an attempt to read a
> creature's thoughts, typically goes unnotice, unless a spell says
> otherwise.

While the Negative Energy Cone isn't a spell, it is a magical effect, and so it is reasonable to apply the same logic.

> **Death Tyrant MM 29**
>
> The death tyrant's central eye emits an invisible, magical 150-foot
> cone of negative energy. At the start of each of its turns, the tyrant
> decides which way the cone faces and whether the cone is active.

> Any
> creature in that area **can't regain hit points**. Any **humanoid that dies
> there becomes a zombie** under the tyrant's command. The dead humanoid
> retrains its place in the initiative order and animates at the start
> of its next turn, provided that its body hasn't been completely
> destroyed.

Nothing in the description of the ability describes any obvious effect, other than when trying to **regain hit points** or **dying**, so creatures won't notice it unless either of those two things occur.

### DMs may allow checks to notice where the central eye is looking

Given that the cone is emitted by the central eye, a DM may reasonably allow a character to try to determine where the cone is being directed, if said character is aware that such a cone exists. However, this is totally up to the DM as there is no specific guidance on this.

### Official ruling guidance concurs.

The *Sage Advice Compendium* contains additional detailed guidance on perceiving spell effects, so again, the logic applies to our magical effect here:

> **Do you always know when you’re under the effect of a spell?**
>
> You’re aware that a spell is affecting you if it has a perceptible effect or if its text says you’re aware of it (see PHB , under “Targets”). Most spells are obvious. For example, fireball burns you, cure wounds heals you, and command forces you to suddenly do something you didn’t intend. Certain spells are more subtle, yet you become aware of the spell at a time specified in the spell’s description. Charm person and detect thoughts are examples of such spells.
>
> Some spells are so subtle that you might not know you were ever under their effects. A prime example of that sort of spell is suggestion. Assuming you failed to notice the spellcaster casting the spell, you might simply remember the caster saying, “The treasure you’re looking for isn’t here. Go look for it in the room at the top of the next tower.” You failed your saving throw, and off you went to the other tower, thinking it was your idea to go there. You and your companions might deduce that you were beguiled if evidence of the spell is found. It’s ultimately up to the DM whether you discover the presence of inconspicuous spells. Discovery usually comes through the use of skills like Arcana, Investigation, Insight, and Perception or through spells like detect magic.

Comment: I would note that while a character may not get any sensation about it, a _learned_ character may recall hearing about Death Tyrants and their Negative Energy Cone, in more or less details. That's what Knowledge checks are about, why they are so important in a party, and why when you have foreknowledge of an encounter you want to research about your opponents' capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

That’s totally up to the DM. There are not any obvious immediate effects, so the default is probably “no”.

I like to give characters clues, and I’m kind of old-school in how I treat magic. For example, in older editions, we played that magic gave you a sensation. If you had to make saving throw for a spell or effect, even if you made it and nothing actually happened, we said you felt a “chill” of magic and knew something tried to happen.

5e doesn’t work like that anymore, and mostly I go with that, but I am still inclined to for some things.

It seems to me that if your body stopped in its natural healing processes, you’d feel something, especially if you were already injured. It would be easy to miss, especially in a combat situation, though. So I would probably do something like have each character in the cone make an INT (Arcana) roll at disadvantage, to tell if they feel something is wrong. If the character is already injured, I’d remove the disadvantage.

I wouldn’t tell them what it was, or what the effects were, but I’d tell them (if they succeeded) that they felt some bad energy when the death tyrant was looking at them.